# How to make "3" in python?

Tags: python, numbers

I would like to make a variable including " and numbers such as "3".

I tried as following:

```
a = "3"
```

but it showed a = '3', and

```
a = '\"'+str(3)+'\"' or a = '"3"'
```

it showed a = '"3"'.

Please help me out to have "3". Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking to have a variable that contains both quotes and numbers? Because that's what your example does.

Comment: You realize that python prints strings surrounded with quotes, right? There's nothing wrong with `a = '"3"'`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I would like to use the result into list such as b[a], so it should be the same as b["3"].

Answer (score 0):

The `'` is not part of `a`, it is just how python tells you it is a string. You've already got your `"3"` by the second code.

```
a = '\"'+str(3)+'\"' or a = '"3"'
```

Comment: It is still '"3"' as result, not "3".